# Twitter data content JSON parsing Issue

Tags: json, twitter

i have a script which i took from this link

```
http://tareq.wedevs.com/2009/05/playing-with-twitter-json-using-php/
```

the script is below

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/SaswatRoutroy.json?count=10", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
$count = count($decode); //counting the number of status
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
  echo $decode[$i]."<br>";
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

it throws me the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/SaswatRoutroy.json?count=10) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Filename: views/recipy_detail.php

Line Number: 116
```

can anybody solve this for me

Comment: Read the error, it says quite explicitly what the problem is. "**404 Not Found**"

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like that URL is throwing a 404, and file_get_contents is accurately throwing an error.

Could you try replacing the URL with one that returns a successful JSON request.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can see response to in your browser to URL http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/SaswatRoutroy.json?count=10

   {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
2. User with username SaswatRoutroy is suspended now.
3. Twitter API was changed. You can get new documentation by [URL](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)